# Select count with Except clause takes too long

Tags: sql-server

I'm executing two queries. One that return the number of records and one that fetch the results. But the query where i only want the total of records , it takes the same time than the query that fetch the results. Why ? Here's my SQL. i'm using SQL 2014 :

```
(SELECT count(*) as id
        FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT title, version
        FROM book AS b
        WHERE b.title IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user AS u WHERE u.column1 = b.column1)
        group by title, version
        EXCEPT
        SELECT DISTINCT title, version
        FROM book AS b
        WHERE b.title IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user AS u WHERE u.column2 = b.column1)
        group by title, version
    ) c )
```

Comment: maybe start with the `sql version`

Comment: and seconded with the actual problem... your query won't help us knowing what you want

Comment: I'm assuming you mean 'Except' Clause?

Comment: yes it's EXCEPT clause. It was a mistake in the title

Comment: To start with, remove sub queries and replace with left joins - that should speed things up

Comment: I tried with JOIN but with sub queries the execution was much faster

Comment: @DanielMarcus - That may not work.  The "except" clause looks for *any* records where `u.column2 = b.column1`.  A join with something like `u.column1 = b.column1 AND NOT u.column2 = b.column1` is not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(SELECT count(*) as id
        FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT title, version
        FROM book  b left join user u on b.column1=u.column1
        WHERE b.title IS NOT NULL and u.column1 is null
        EXCEPT
        SELECT DISTINCT title, version
        FROM book b join user u on b.column1=u.column2
        WHERE b.title IS NOT NULL  
    ) c )
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the JOIN or the Subquery. It's more with the count syntax that i'm trying to figure it how to fix it. Even with the count, it still fetching each row, hence my problem

Comment: subquery will always slow things down

Comment: When i execute the queries seperatly, they are executed in less than  1 sec. First query return 450 records and second one 40 records. At the end, i should have 410 records. So i think the problem comes from the EXCEPT clause cause it takes 15 sec to excecute !

Comment: Oh ok I see - have you tried replacing except with another command? Something like 'where title not in' or left joining to the second query etc

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . for performance, try removing the `group by` and `select distinct` (`except` does this anyway):

```
SELECT count(*) as id
FROM (SELECT title, version
      FROM book b
      WHERE b.title IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user u WHERE u.column1 = b.column1)
      EXCEPT
      SELECT title, version
      FROM book b
      WHERE b.title IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user u WHERE u.column2 = b.column1)
    ) c;
```

Next:  Be sure you have an index on `user(column2)` and `user(column1)`.

With more information about the data, it might be possible to make further suggestions.

Comment: Only the id column had a primary key and was indexed. What type of index i need to add for column 1 and column 2 ? Columnstores Index or Index ? I added index for column 1 and column 2 and now the query is executed after 6 sec instead of 14 sec :)  But the count still get executed after 6 sec as well, same as when i fetch all the rows ! Usally the count should be faster no ?

Comment: When i execute the two subqueries seperatly, both are executed in less that 1 sec !  Maybe i will create a function that output the count delta of the two queries !